# Extract properties from multiple JSON arrays using Jolt transformation

Tags: transform, jolt

My JSON object looks like following:

```json
{
  "array1": [
    {
      "key1": "value1", // common key
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1", // common key
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
    }
  ],
  "includes": {
    "array2": [
      {
        "key1": "value1", // common key
        "key4": "value4",
        "key5": "value5"
      },
      {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key4": "value4",
        "key5": "value5"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to have the output in following format -

```json
[ 
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4", // this comes from joining with array 2 based on key1
    "key5": "value5"  // this comes from joining with array 2 based on key1
  }, 
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4", // this comes from joining with array 2 based on key1
    "key5": "value5"  // this comes from joining with array 2 based on key1
  }
]
```

I only have a solution to fetch fields from array1 but **unsure how to join with array2 based on common key, fetch required fields and represent them in a desired way**.

Current Transformation :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "key1": "[&1].key1",
          "key2": "[&1].key2",
          "key3": "[&1].key3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Current undesired output :

```json
[ 
  {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
    "key3" : "value3"
  }, 
  {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
    "key3" : "value3"
  } 
]
```

Any help would be appreciated here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in order to get "the undesired output", need to replace **`"data"`** with **`"*"`** wildcard within the current transformation spec, and no need to repeat each attribute key name and value branch, only using this spec is enough

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

if you'd nest one more level as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

then, you'd get

```json
[ 
  {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key4" : "value4",
    "key5" : "value5"
  }, 
  {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key4" : "value4",
    "key5" : "value5"
  } 
]
```

We can use **`"*"`** and **`"@"`** wildcards at different levels of objects in order to combine those results, but this case the values of key name **`"key1"`** would repeat of course. We can get rid of that repeating by adding a **cardinality** transformation , and get your desired result such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "[&1].&"
          },
          "@": "[&1]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: This works great. Thank you so much, @Barbaros. 
A follow-up... What would we need to change in your transformation, to match the keys if we have array1>key1 with a matching value in array2>key4?

Comment: I have accepted your answer, and opened another question for my other specific scenario - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020094/combine-json-arrays-based-on-common-key-using-jolt.
Thanks again, for your help.