# Combine JSON arrays based on common key using Jolt

Tags: json, transform, jolt

My JSON object looks like following:

```json
{
  "array1": [
    {
      "key1": "value1", // common key
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1", // common key
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
    }
  ],
  "includes": {
    "array2": [
      {
        "key4": "value1", // common key
        "key5": "value5"
      },
      {
        "key4": "value1", // common key
        "key5": "value5"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to have the output in following format -

```json
[ 
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key5": "value5"  // this comes from joining with array 2 based on key1 & key4
  }, 
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key5": "value5"  // this comes from joining with array 2 based on key1 & key4
  }
]
```

Based on [Extract properties from multiple JSON arrays using Jolt transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72017653/extract-properties-from-multiple-json-arrays-using-jolt-transformation), I have an answer to make above work if same keys exist in both arrays (for ex: array1>key1 & array2>key1). But, in this case, both arrays have different keys (array1>key1 & array2>key4) with same values of course.

Please suggest how to match the keys in this case, and get the desired output. Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't understand why we pick key5-value5 pair while doesn't key4-value4 pair. How can we know that key4-value4 is common?

Comment: In above case, I meant to say key1-value1 (array1) is same as key4-value1 (array2). Just edited the original question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: In our output, since key1-value1 is already captured, we probably don't need to capture key4-value1 again. To provide further clarification, think of the following example: id as key1 - 123 as value1 and user_id as key4 - 123 as value1. id & user_id really have the same value, but just represented differently in array 2 as compared to array1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use successive **shift** transformation specs such as

```json
[
  { // combine key-value pairs of the arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "[&1].&"
          },
          "@": "[&1]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // exchange key-value pairs, and take keys under common values which are pretended to be key names now 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2.@(0)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick the first component for the Right Hand Side if they're list of keys
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of key names of the objects 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: This is a great suggestion. Thanks @Barbaros.